# Migrating activiti from 5.22.0 to 6.0.0 results in IllegalThreadStateException when deploying

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

We are currently using v5.22.0 of activiti with process engine programmatically configured as follows:

```
public class ProgrammaticProcessEngineConfiguration implements ProcessEngineLookup {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProgrammaticProcessEngineConfiguration.class.getCanonicalName());

private ProcessEngine processEngine;

private ManagedThreadFactory managedThreadFactory;

@Override
public ProcessEngine getProcessEngine() {
    managedThreadFactory = getThreadFactory();
    final ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    final ManagedAsyncJobExecutor managedJobExecutor = new ManagedAsyncJobExecutor() {

        @Override
        protected void startExecutingAsyncJobs() {
            if (threadFactory == null) {
                super.startExecutingAsyncJobs();
            } else {
                if (threadPoolQueue == null) { threadPoolQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(queueSize); }
                if (executorService == null) {
                    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, threadPoolQueue, threadFactory) {
                        @Override
                        protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { t.setContextClassLoader(classLoader); }
                    };
                    threadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
                    executorService = threadPoolExecutor;
                }
                startJobAcquisitionThread();
            }
        }
    };

    managedJobExecutor.setThreadFactory(managedThreadFactory);

    final CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration cdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration = new CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration();
    cdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
    processEngine = cdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE)
            .setDataSourceJndiName("something").setDatabaseType("something")
            .setHistoryLevel(HistoryLevel.NONE)
            .setTransactionsExternallyManaged(true).setJobExecutorActivate(true)
            .setAsyncExecutorEnabled(true)
            .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
            .setAsyncExecutor(managedJobExecutor)
            .setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
            .buildProcessEngine();
    return processEngine;
}
```

When migrating to v6.0.0, we want backwards compatibility behaviour for process instances maintained, hence setting the following:

`cdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration.setActiviti5CompatibilityEnabled(true);`

We need the process engine to support both JTA and CDI.  However, the instructions on migration page (https://www.activiti.org/migration) isn't very clear and I am not sure how to configure the process engine.

I get the following error: `Unsupported process engine configuration` when compatibility mode is activated.

Is anyone familiar with migrating activiti to v6.0.0 using CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the illegal thread state exception is due to your `threadPoolExecutor` try creating engine without it and deploy your code